# Do you know any tools to switch from external/internal stylesheet to inline style?

Tags: css

I'm looking for a tool which uses the CSS selectors within a stylesheet to generate the selected inline style.

E.g :

```
<head>
<style text="text/css">
a {
   text-decoration: none;
}

#a, #b, #c
{
   position: absolute;
}

#b
{
   left: 50px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="a">
    <p>
     <a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com">SO</a>
    </p>
  </div>
  <div id="b">
  </div>
  <div id="c">
  </div>
</body>
```

will be :

```
<body>
  <div id="a" style="position: absolute">
    <p>
     <a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com" style="text-decoration: none;">SO</a>
    </p>
  </div>
  <div id="b" style="position: absolute; left: 50px;">
  </div>
  <div id="c" style="position: absolute">
  </div>
</body>
```

Any ideas ?!

**EDIT :**

I want to do that to be able to 'style' email in most email client, especially for gmail, which doesn't support external or even internal stylesheet.

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: I don't know of any... maybe because it's kind of taking a step backwards.

Answer (score 1):

you can do it with the following online application:

[Convert CSS to inline styles](http://www.soldesignco.com/dev-csstoinline.php)

Comment: Wow, what's the benfit in this?

Comment: mostly used for email send through gmail, they dont support css in headers.. ;)

Comment: Yeah but then wouldn't you develop styles especially for email sending? But ok I get that this could be helpful for newsletter and so on

Comment: it's usefull, when you develop newsletter like a classic html page, with firebug, and so on. Inline styling from hand it's just painfull and messy.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to pass it through an API and do it automatically from within your application, check out http://premailer.dialect.ca.

It's a lot easier to use an API integrated into your app if you're developing one, since you don't have to generate the email contents and

If you're using ruby, the project is open sourced [here](https://github.com/alexdunae/premailer/) so you can integrate it directly.

Or if you're using node.js, there's a wrapper that makes the API even easier to use: https://github.com/JedWatson/node-premailer

If you prefer to use a web form, MailChimp have a great tool [here](http://beaker.mailchimp.com/inline-css). Mailchimp have an [API](http://apidocs.mailchimp.com/api/1.3/inlinecss.func.php) too if you've got an account.